# Search Results do not display PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql

We are trying to do a search form with 7 search criteria for a database with 8 attributes. But we only want to search one event at a time. This is the code I have so far and would like to display the searched information into the table. Any help to know where to look would bee appreciated.

```
<?php
include 'database_connector.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $type = $_POST['type'];
 $team1 = $_POST['team1'];
 $team2 = $_POST['team2'];
 $place = $_POST['place'];
 $year = $_POST['year'];
 $month = $_POST['month'];
 $day = $_POST['day'];
 $price = $_POST['price'];
 $date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
  if($type)(
    $result=mysqli_connect($con, "select * from Sports where `Event Type` = '$type'")
    );
if($team1)(
$result1=mysqli_connect($con, "select * from Sports where `Team 1` = '$team1'")
);
if($team2)(
$result2=mysqli_connect($con, "select * from Sports where `Team 2` = '$team2'")
);  
if($place)(
$result3=mysqli_connect($con, "select * from Sports where `Place` = '$place'")
);
if($date)(
$result4=mysqli_connect($con, "select * from Sports where `Date` = '$date'")
);
if($price)(
$result5=mysqli_connect($con, "select * from Sports where `Price` = '$price'")
);
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by you only want to search one event at a time?

Comment: One search field at a time. i.e. search for a event type being football and none of the rest of the form is filled out.

Comment: you should be calling `mysqli_query`, not `mysqli_connect`. And you should use parametrized queries instead of substituting variables.

Comment: But what should happen if the user fills in multiple fields? Which of them should be searched?

Comment: Nothing is going to happen this is a project and once we present it is going off line. I fixed the connect part. How do you do the parametrized queries

Comment: did your $_POST value follow sequence?

Comment: it is posted in sequential order

Answer (score 0):

Use `if/elseif/` to perform just one query, and assign the results to the same variable:

```
if ($type) {
    $query = "select * from Sports where `Event Type` = '$type'";
} elseif ($team1) {
    $query = "select * from Sports where `Team 1` = '$team1'";
} ...
} else {
    die("You must fill in one of the search fields");
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Code to display each row of results
}
```

Comment: Where does the $result go I have it in my table along with the new php if statements

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, there's no formatting. But I think that's right.

Comment: http://notnormalmotorsports.com/NiteKrawler/sports.php this is the page try it your self. It will not display on the table below the search form

Comment: There's no way for me to tell what's happening in PHP. BTW, `$date` will never be empty, so it will never fall through to the `Price` search.

Comment: I commented the elseif date out

Comment: What should I search for? I don't know any of your team names. Not that I can tell what's going wrong when I try.

Comment: In your pastebin you're missing the `</form>` at the end of the form.

Comment: You don't have an input with `name="submit"`, so `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` will never be true.

Comment: Thank you it was the name=submit works just fine thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Use same variable if you want to execute only one statement and `if/elseif/`

```
if($type){
    $result=mysqli_connect($con, "select * from Sports where `Event Type` = '$type'")
    }
elseif($team1){
$result=mysqli_connect($con, "select * from Sports where `Team 1` = '$team1'")
}
elseif($team2){
$result=mysqli_connect($con, "select * from Sports where `Team 2` = '$team2'")
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't your code show what you said in the answer?